# Endymion, the Mighty Master of Magic vs Starlight Road

Tags: yu-gi-oh

My opponent controlled "Endymion, the Mighty Master of Magic" on their Pendulum zone and has 6 Spell counters scattered on his part of the field. I controlled 2 face-down cards on my S/T zone, one of which is "Starlight Road". My opponent activates the effect of "Endymion, the Mighty Master of Magic" and removed 6 Spell counters as cost.

Can I activate "Starlight Road" in response to "Endymion, the Mighty Master of Magic" Pendulum effect?

> Pendulum Effect:

> You can remove 6 Spell Counters from your field; Special Summon this card from the Pendulum Zone, then count the number of cards you control that can have a Spell Counter, destroy up to that many cards on the field, and if you do, place Spell Counters on this card equal to the number of cards destroyed. You can only use this effect of "Endymion, the Mighty Master of Magic" once per turn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No, Starlight Road cannot be activated.

In order to chain Starlight Road, it must be certain that 2 or more cards will be destroyed at the time of resolution; see various [OCG rulings](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Card_Rulings:Starlight_Road):

**Dark Master Zorc/Time Wizard**

> "Starlight Road" cannot be Chained to the activation of effects like that of "Dark Master - Zorc" or "Time Wizard", since it is unknown whether or not the effect will destroy two cards on your side of the field.

**Elemental Hero Stratos**

> If the effect of "Elemental Hero Stratos" which destroys Spell/Trap Cards is activated, then when resolving the effect its controller can choose to not destroy any Spell/Trap Cards. Thus, "Starlight Road" cannot be Chained to this effect, since it is unknown whether or not the effect of "Elemental Hero Stratos" will destroy two Spell/Trap Cards you control.

As Endymion's effect destroys "up to" that many cards on the field, the player can theoretically choose to destroy fewer than two cards, so Starlight Road cannot be activated.

Comment: What about "Stardust Dragon"? It doesn't specify the number, can it be chained to Endymion?

Comment: It cannot, for the same reason as above; it has to be certain that cards will be destroyed at resolution, but the player using Endymion's effect can opt to destroy no cards.

Comment: But the destruction is mandatory, since Endymion can put Spell Counter on itself, therefore a minimum of 1 card would be destroyed, isn't it?

Comment: It's true that destroying "up to that many cards on the field" is mandatory, but "up to" allows for the choice of zero cards unless the card specifically contains the text "(min 1)." So no, it's not technically guaranteed that anything must be destroyed. Even if the player's field is full of cards that can have spell counters placed on them, that player can still say "Yeah, I won't destroy anything."